# Correct way of passing a View subclass to AsyncTask

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-asynctask

I've seen post where they pass a `View` to an `AsyncTask` using `SoftReference` or `Set` or `WeakReference`. I have never used this 3 classes before, so I'd want to know if this is absolutely necessary to prevent context memory leak and if so, how to do it?